# facebook connect in my site

Tags: facebook

I'm trying to use facebook connect in my website for the first time.

I've created an app and I copied the code from here  AS IS to a blank HTML file
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/#login

but all I see is a plain text - "Login with Facebook" - no button, no functionality.

what can be the problem?

The code is -

```
<html>
    <head>
      <title>My Facebook Login Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="fb-root"></div>
      <script>
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
          FB.init({
            appId      : 'XXXXXXX',
            status     : true, 
            cookie     : true,
            xfbml      : true
          });
        };
        (function(d){
           var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
           js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
           js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
           d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
         }(document));
      </script>
      <div class="fb-login-button">Login with Facebook</div>
    </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Any updates on this question?

Comment: I gave up and did it in another way.. thank you all

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an XML namespace to the <html> tag of your document.

```
<html xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
```

...then try the following for your login button:

```
<fb:login-button></fb:login-button>
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I noticed from your HTML code, you lack the  tag that links to Facebook's JS SDK.

Add this:

```
 <script src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId={YOUR_FACEBOOK_APP_ID}&xfbml=1"></script>
```

Then instead of doing

```
 <div class="fb-login-button">Login with Facebook</div>
```

do

```
 <fb:login-button></fb:login-button>
```

just as what Charley P. answered.

Answer (score -1):

Try to run your application in host. if your project is php based project means run in https://localhost/projectname.

And also check your facebook app setting. your project name should same as site name.